# Perception of curvature of human eye

Tags: optics, curvature, vision, biology, perception

How are human eyes able to detect the different curvatures of surface ? Basically how are the human eyes able to differentiate between a plane surface and a convex or a concave surface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about [biology.se] than physics.

Comment: Curiously, the human eye feels comfortable with concave curvature, but not with convex.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible because we have two eyes. They furnish depth perception, which lets us perceive curvatures.

Even with only one eye, we can be fooled into believing a perfectly flat 2-D surface is curved in 3 dimensions by processing cues of color, shading and perspective based on experience. This is the reason that we can "understand" a painting or a printed picture as representing 3-dimensional objects when the rendering itself is strictly 2-dimensional.

So, curvatures can be perceived because we have stereoscopic vision and because we have image-processing programs running in our brains that help identify curvature.

Answer (score 2):

Although stereoscopic vision can be useful for perceiving curvature of surfaces, in my experience shading (in the case of diffusive surfaces) is more important.  Curvature in a specular surface is also easy to perceive using only one eye, because concave and convex mirrors impose different distortions on reflected scenes.  Also, a person with vision in only one eye can easily learn to perceive curvature almost as well as a person with normal vision.  Consider what you perceive when looking at a photograph of a curved surface.  You perceive the curvature correctly most of the time, despite the fact that the photo was shot from a single point perspective.  All that said, it's a bit easier to fool a single eye than a pair of eyes, into misinterpreting a scene.  Bottom line: it is not so much a property of the eye or eyes that allows us to see curvature.  Rather, it is our brain that makes it possible.